# How to call a contract function from ReactJS, that takes a struct as an argument?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethers.js, react

I am struggling to figure out how to actually call a function (using React) in a contract that takes a struct as an argument (which also has another struct in it) ?

The contract function looks like this:

```
function createCampaign(CampaignInput calldata input_) external {
//code here
}
```

The structs that are involved are:

```
struct ItemInput {
    string name;
    uint256 value;
    uint256 supply;

}

struct CampaignInput {
    string name;
    uint256 campaignType;
    ItemInput[] items; 
}
```

I have loaded the contract using Ethers.js in React and I am trying to call it using this code, which is obviously very wrong:

```
contract.createCampaign({"name",0,[]})
```

Other methods, that do not have a struct as an argument, work just fine using the method above.

My question is what do I need to write in the line above so that I can pass the proper arguments to the contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on your js library that is used to interact with the contract.

For `Ethers` (and probably also `web3js`) you can either use an object **with keys** or nested arrays.

So for your example:

```js
const items = [
  {
    name: "Item 1",
    value: 0,
    supply: 100
  }
]
contract.createCampaign({ name: "name", campaignType : 0, items })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue representing a struct as a dict using ethers.js. If anyone is having issues from passing a struct as a javascript dict, an array might work:

`[value1, value2]`

instead of

`{key1 : value1, key2: value2}`
didn't work but